# How to manage a dictionary with a list of tuples

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

I have the following data structure I want to work with:

```
tracker = {"Person1": [(locationA, timeA),(locationB, timeB)], 
           "Person2": [(locationA, timeC),(locationB, timeD)}
```

I want to be able to go through the list of places seen for that person and for a particular location if the time is more than X seconds then UPDATE the time for that location/person whilst not changing/removing the data for the other people in the dictionary or the other locations for that person.

Whats the best way to work with this data structure ? collections, dictionaries, lists, etc.

I could write some simple logic like:

```
for i in tracker["Person1"]:
   if i[0] == "locationA" and time.time() - i[1] > X:

       ( logic to update the element - help needed here )
```

This doesn't seem elegant or efficient and I am guessing there is a better way to work with this data.

Comment: Did you mean: `i[0] = ("locationA", time.time())`?

Comment: sorry... may have got that wrong... I meant to say go through the list places/times seen for that person and check what the time is for a specific location so the logic I wanted was check if (location) AND (time was > X seconds).

Comment: In that case [edit] your question and change it to what you meant.

Comment: Im slightly confused, will the new item (same location but updated time) replace the first item or will it be a new item in the list? Your question needs to be clearer.

Comment: For PersonA .. if I see them at locationA and the time is > X seconds then UPDATE...the time at that location for that person.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions. Will try them out and see what works best for me.

Answer (score 1):

List comprehension is useful for this.

```
[x if update_condition else update_func(x) for x in i if delete_condition ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You use

```
for i in tracker["Person1"]:
```

which loops through one entry of a dictionary. If you want to use only "person1" I would suggest to address this directly like:

```
tracker["Person1"][0]
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want something like this:

```
for i, (location, last_seen) in enumerate(tracker["Person1"]):
    if location == "locationA" and time.time() - last_seen > X:
       tracker["Person1"][i] = (location, time.time())
```

Using `enumerate` gives you the index of the item you want to change, and using tuple unpacking, you don't need to use `item[0]` and `item[1]` to get the constituent parts of the tuple.